# python, functions running from a list and adding to a list through functions

Tags: python, function, list

How do I run a function on a loop so all the results go straight into a list and is there a way to run a function which acts on all the values in a list?

Comment: I agree with untypable name, you need to clarify, use an example

Comment: @Vinko: untypable, but not uncopiable :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theres a couple ways to run a function on a loop like that - You can either use a list comprehension

```
test = list('asdf')
[function(x) for x in test]
```

and use that result

Or you could use the map function

```
test = list('asdf')
map(function, test)
```

The first answer is more "pythonic", while the second is more functional.

EDIT: The second way is also a lot faster, as it's not running arbitrary code to call a function, but directly calling a function using `map`, which is implemented in C.

Comment: important note - the second way is much, much faster

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs clarification.

#### run a function on a loop

```
new_list= [yourfunction(item) for item in a_sequence]
```

#### run a function acting on all values in a list

Your function should have some form of iteration in its code to process all items of a sequence, something like:

```
def yourfunction(sequence):
    for item in sequence:
        …
```

Then you just call it with a sequence (i.e. a list, a string, an iterator etc)

```
yourfunction(range(10))
yourfunction("a string")
```

YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to do it (run it in an interpreter)

```
>>> def square(x):
...  return x*x
...
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

>>> map(square,a)
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```